# clang-tidy: How to suppress warnings?

Tags: suppress-warnings, clang-static-analyzer, clang-tidy

I recently started experimenting with the `clang-tidy` tool of llvm. Now I am trying to suppress false warnings from third party library code. For this I want to use the command line options

`-header-filter=<string>` or `-line-filter=<string>`

but so far without success. So for people with limited time I will put the question here at the beginning and explain later what I already tried.

#### Question

**What option do I need to give to the `clang-tidy` tool to suppress a warning from a certain line and file?**

if this is not possible

**What option works to suppress warnings from external header files?**

---

#### What I did so far

My original call to clang-tidy looks like this

```
clang-tidy-3.8 -checks=-*,clang-analyzer-*,-clang-analyzer-alpha* -p Generated/LinuxMakeClangNoPCH Sources/CodeAssistant/ModuleListsFileManipulator_fixtures.cpp
```

and the first line of the yielded warning that I want to suppress looks like this

```
.../gmock/gmock-spec-builders.h:1272:5: warning: Use of memory after it is freed [clang-analyzer-cplusplus.NewDelete]
    return function_mocker_->AddNewExpectation(
```

The gmock people told me that this is a false positive so I want to suppress it. First I tried to use the `-line-filter=<string>` option. The documentation says:

```
  -line-filter=<string>      - List of files with line ranges to filter the
                               warnings. Can be used together with
                               -header-filter. The format of the list is a JSON
                               array of objects:
                                 [
                                   {"name":"file1.cpp","lines":[[1,3],[5,7]]},
                                   {"name":"file2.h"}
                                 ]
```

I assumed that warnings in the given lines are filtered out. But the doc doesent say if they are filterd out or in.
After some fiddeling arround I created a .json file with the content

```
[
  {"name":"gmock-spec-builders.h","lines":[[1272,1272]]}
]
```

and modified the command line to

```
clang-tidy-3.8 -checks=-*,clang-analyzer-*,-clang-analyzer-alpha* -p Generated/LinuxMakeClangNoPCH -line-filter="$(< Sources/CodeAssistant/CodeAssistant_ClangTidySuppressions.json)" Sources/CodeAssistant/ModuleListsFileManipulator_fixtures.cpp
```

which writes the content of the file into the argument. This suppresses the warning, but not only this warning, but all warnings from the ModuleListsFileManipulator_fixtures.cpp file. I tried more stuff but I could not make it work.

So I tried the `-header-filter=<string>` option. Here the documentation states that one has to give a regular expression that matches all the header files from which diagnostics shall be displayed. Ok, I thought, lets use a regualar expression that matches everything that is in the same folder as the analyzed .cpp file. I can live with that although it may remove warnings that result from me using external headers wrong.

Here I was not sure if the regular expression must match the full (absolute) filename or only a part of the filename. I tried

```
-header-filter=.*\/CodeAssistant\/.*.h
```

which matches all absolute header filenames in the CodeAssistant folder but it did not suppress the warnings from the gmock-spec-builders.h file.

So preferably I would like to suppress each warning individually so I can determine for each if it is a real problem or not, but if this is not possible I could also live with suppressing warnings from entire external headers.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding *// NOLINT* to line *1790* of *gmock-spec-builders.h*

Here is the diff:

```
--- gmock-spec-builders.orig.h  2016-09-17 09:46:48.527313088 +0200
+++ gmock-spec-builders.h       2016-09-17 09:46:58.958353697 +0200
@@ -1787,7 +1787,7 @@
 #define ON_CALL(obj, call) GMOCK_ON_CALL_IMPL_(obj, call)

 #define GMOCK_EXPECT_CALL_IMPL_(obj, call) \
-    ((obj).gmock_##call).InternalExpectedAt(__FILE__, __LINE__, #obj, #call)
+    ((obj).gmock_##call).InternalExpectedAt(__FILE__, __LINE__, #obj, #call) // NOLINT
 #define EXPECT_CALL(obj, call) GMOCK_EXPECT_CALL_IMPL_(obj, call)

 #endif  // GMOCK_INCLUDE_GMOCK_GMOCK_SPEC_BUILDERS_H_
```

It would be nice to either upstream this patch (I see other NOLINT in the code) or post a bug report with the clang-tidy folks.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/853) is the discussion I had on github with the googletest guys. They could have mentioned that they already suppress warnings. I was too lazy to register with the llvm mailing list to post the false positive. Which tools understand the // NOLINT comment?

Comment: The // NOLINT is picked up by the clang tooling.
From reading the discussion I think this is not really a false positive it is more like a thing that can "never" happen. So I think the best approach is the NOLINT solution.

Comment: Strangely your fix doesn't solve the problem for me in all cases. I also have to put the // NOLINT behind line 1272 ````return function_mocker_->AddNewExpectation( // NOLINT````

Comment: I think I will propose a change to googletest anyways because I can not suppress the warnings with the command line options. But what to do if the dependency can not be changed. Then you have to put the // NOLINT all over the place which is somewhat ugly.

Answer (score 6):

I have found another non-invasive (without adding `// NOLINT` to a third-party library) way to suppress warnings. For example, the current version of Google Test fails some `cppcoreguidelines-*` checks. The following code allows you to validate the current diff excluding lines that contain gtest's macros:

```sh
git diff -U3 | sed '
    s/^+\( *TEST(\)/ \1/;
    s/^+\( *EXPECT_[A-Z]*(\)/ \1/;
    s/^+\( *ASSERT_[A-Z]*(\)/ \1/;
' | recountdiff | interdiff -U0 /dev/null /dev/stdin | clang-tidy-diff.py -p1 -path build
```

It assumes that file `build/compile_commands.json` is generated before and `clang-tidy-diff.py` is available from your environment. `recountdiff` and `interdiff` from [patchutils](https://github.com/twaugh/patchutils) are the standard tools for manipulating patches.

The script works as follows:

1. `git diff -U3` generates a patch with 3 context lines.
2. `sed ...` removes prefix `+` from the undesired lines, i.e. transform them to the context.
3. `recountdiff` correct offsets (in first ranges) in the chunk headers.
4. `interdiff -U0 /dev/null /dev/stdin` just removes all context lines from a patch. As a result, it splits the initial hunks.
5. `clang-tidy-diff.py` reads only second ranges from chunk headers and passes them to `clang-tidy` via `-line-filter` option.

**UPD:** It's important to provide `interdiff` with a sufficient number of context lines, otherwise it may produce some artifacts in the result. See the citation from `man interdiff`:

> For best results, the diffs must have at least three lines of context.

Particularly, I have found that `git diff -U0 | ... | interdiff` generates some spurious literals `$!otj` after splitting chunks.

Answer (score 4):

Use `-isystem` instead of `-I` to set your system and 3rd party include paths. `-I` should only be used to include code that is part of the project being built.

This is the only thing required to make `clang-tidy` ignore all errors in external code. All the other answers (at the point of writing) are just poor workarounds for something that is perfectly solved with `-isystem`.

If you use a build system like CMake or Meson it will automatically set `-I` and `-isystem` correctly for you.

`-isystem` is also the mechanism that is used for telling compilers, at least GCC and Clang, what's not your code. If you start to use `-isystem` you can also enable more compiler warnings without getting "false positives" from external code.

Comment: This sounds interesting. I wont be able to check if that works right away. But maybe in the chrismas holidays.

Comment: The only issue I'm having is how to disable errors and warnings for expanded macros out of those system headers.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't achive what I wanted with the commmand line options, so I will use the `// NOLINT` comments in the cpp files which was proposed by the accepted answer.

I will also try to push the fix to googletest.

I found out that lines in the `-line-filter` options are filtered in.
But giving concrete lines is no real solution for my problem anyways.
I rather need a suppression mechanism like it is implemented in Valgrind.